# How do I get a "template event" through a JS-event in Google Polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

Hopefully I can explain this :)

If I attach an event listener via a template:

```
<some-node on-event='{{ eventHandler }}'>
```

I get a function signature of:

```
function eventHandler( ev, data, node ){
```

However, if I attach it via JS:

```
this.$.someNode.addEventListener( 'event', this.eventHandler.bind( this ) );
```

I don't receive `data` or `node`, only the event:

```
function eventHandler( ev );
```

I realize that this data is available via `ev.detail` and `ev.path`, but it's annoying to have to constantly keep track of *how* I attached an event in order to determine the data I'm receiving.  Is there a way to attach an event, in Polymer, that will natively unwrap the event object into the `ev, data, node` signature?